# Auth0 NodeJS Authentification Refused using npm request

Tags: angularjs, node.js, web-applications, auth0

I'm facing a problem, I tried to connect to Auth0 API to enable a strong identification on my WebApp.

For context :

- Front-End : I'm using an angularJS front, and there I implemented the [Lock](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock) Library to manage the Auth0 popup by following this webapp-specific [tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2/oauth-web-protocol).
- Back-End : NodeJS & Express server, in order to verify the user's authentification, I use the npm lib "request" to call the Auth0 API.

If i understand well, a click on the auth0 widget sends a request to the specified endpoint URL, and it's received by the back-end:

```
    app.get('/auth0CallbackURL', function (req, res) {
      console.log(req.query.code);
      var auth0code     = req.query.code;
      var client_secret = PROCESS.ENV.SERCRETID;
      var domain        = PROCESS.ENV.DOMAIN;
      var client_id     = PROCESS.ENV.CLIENTID;
      var redirectUrl   = PROCESS.ENV.REDIRECTURL;

      var request = require('request'); // request-promise
      var requestParams = {
        url: 'https://mycompanydomain.auth0.com/oauth/token?client_id='+client_id+'&redirect_uri='+redirectUrl+'&client_secret='+client_secret+'&code='+auth0code+'&grant_type=authorization_code',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      }
```

And then I call request() to get back the access_token and verify the authentification.

```
    request(requestParams, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
      console.log('Err:', err);
      } else {
      console.log('response body: ', data.body)
      }
```

But the only result I get is :

```
    {
      "error": "access_denied"
      "error_description": "Unauthorized"
    }
```

At the begining i thougt it was my Auth0 configuration that's didn't allow my authentification, but it seems that there are OK.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the page you linked, you need to pass the following information:

```
client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
&redirect_uri=https://YOUR_APP/callback
&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET
&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE
&grant_type=authorization_code
```

in the **request body** and with a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

You're setting the content type correctly, but then are passing the data in the URL query component and **instead you need to pass it the `POST` request body**.

Using [request package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) you should do the following:

```
var requestParams = {
    url: 'https://mycompanydomain.auth0.com/oauth/token',
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'client_id=' + client_id + 
        '&redirect_uri=' + redirectUrl + 
        '&client_secret=' + client_secret + 
        '&code=' + auth0code + 
        '&grant_type=authorization_code',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}
```